# How to load HikariConfig from custom properties in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to create a custom HikariConfig bean in my application so I can manipulate it and use it to create two different HikariDataSource objects. I thought it would be simple to do using something like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
@Component
public class MyConfig extends HikariConfig {
 private String xxx;

 public void setXxx(String xxx) {
  this.xxx = xxx;
 }
}
```

Now if I have `myprefix.xxx=qqq` in application.properties then field `xxx` is successfully initialized to `qqq`, but the rest of HikariConfig's fields are not. No amount of playing with the prefix (myprefix, datasource, dataSource etc.) seemed to do the trick.

Looking at HikariConfig's source it can either initialize itself using a properties file or a Properties object, but I can't figure out the right way to do this through Spring. Any ideas?